# Iterate req.body to object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to map data from req.body to object before insert to database

```
//object
var user = {
  name : "",
  age  : "",
  address : ""
}

router.route('/insertuser').post(function (req, res) {
    //iterate req.body values to matching user object value
});
```

is it possible to iterate or buffer req.body to matching given object's value? thank you before

Comment: Could you provide a little more info?. Are you trying to find these values in req.body?Is the structure of req.body fixed or is it dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to create a new object that has the same properties as your `user` object, but gets the values from `req.body`, then you can do that like this:

```
//object
var user = {
  name : "",
  age  : "",
  address : ""
}
router.route('/insertuser').post(function (req, res) {
    let newObj = {};
    Object.keys(user).forEach(function(prop) {
        newObj[prop] = req.body[prop];
    });
    // newObj is populated with name, age and address properties from req.body
});
```

Comment: Great answer this one!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a rather recent version of nodejs you can probably do this:

```
var {name, age, address} = req.body
var user = {name, age, address}
```

Comment: If the OP looking to run through unknown keys then?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
//object
var userObject = {
  name : "",
  age  : "",
  address : ""
}

router.route('/insertuser').post(function (req, res) {
    newObject = {}
    Object.keys(userObject).map(function(key, index) {
        newObject[key] = req.body[key] 
    });

    // Then save the userObject to the database. 
});
```