# Can't access POST parameters dynamically in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the a datatable send the parameters

When i retrieve **req.body** for my post i have the full result

```
app.post('/folder/service', (req, res)=>{
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    let response;

    response = req.body;

    res.send(response);
});
```

result

```
action: edit
data[CODE]: 1
data[DESCRIPTION]: TEST
```

**req.body["data[DESCRIPTION]"]** works too

but i trying get the parameters dinamically

Ps: i saw the way to retrieve the parameters in **get** using **req.param("data")** but don't work on **post**

Comment: That's because neither GET nor POST have a concept of parameters, the concepts of parameters come from CGI/1.1 and you are required to parse that out. GET gets parsed and put into `req.params.XXX` whereas POST gets parsed an shoved into `req.body.XXX`  in order to get the `keys` you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005736/iterate-req-body-to-object

Answer (score 0):

You should use `req.body.[property name]`. For example: `req.body.description`

Comment: I think the OP may want to get the keys as well.